# What's the easiest way to kill a Crusher in Radiant Defense?

Tags: radiant-defense

I'm on the final wave of the Level 11: Jaws and I keep getting pwned by the Crusher. I killed him once already in the last level, but that required converting pretty much every weapon into a Seraphim missile launcher -- a strategy that doesn't work as well when I have to also defend against 20 Tauruss.

I can't imagine any way of killing it without the bonus packs either.

What weapons excel against the Crusher, and is there a strategy (beyond the obvious) with regards to killing it?